# reading and writing a large txt file in node.js causing exception

Tags: node.js, multithreading, io, child-process

I have a large txt file of size approx ~ 1GB. I am trying to read the contents from the this file and write to another file.My code is -->

```
var fs = require("fs"); 
var fb = fs.openSync('./copy.txt','r+');
fs.open('./largefile.txt','r',function(error,fd){
    fs.fstat(fd,function(error,stats){
        var totalFileSize = stats.size,
            chunk = 512,
            buffer = new Buffer(512),
            bytesRead = 0;

        while(bytesRead < totalFileSize){
            if((totalFileSize - bytesRead) < chunk){
                chunk = totalFileSize - bytesRead ;
            }
            fs.read(fd,buffer,0,chunk,bytesRead,function(err, bytesRead, buffer){
                 fs.write(fb,buffer,0,chunk,bytesRead,function(err,written,buffer){});
            });
            bytesRead = bytesRead + chunk;  
        }   
    });
});
```

I got this error console ->

```
FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - process out of memory
```

Q1) What could I am possibly doing wrong?
Q2) Are there any benefits of doing that in child_process?If yes, should I use fork() or spawn() and how?(I am new to node.js and find child_process pretty confusing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of the `fs` functions you're using are asynchronous, so you're effectively trying to open `copy.txt` thousands of times simultaneously.

It looks like you're also never updating `bytesRead` so your while loop will run forever.

Comment: Well, I have changed some code and make sure that copy.txt is opened only once , but I have to work the asynchronous way, so that my main thread never blocks. Still getting the exception.